# Build a binary classifier for biomedical documents (to curate or to discard)

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, text-mining, bert-language-model

I want to build a binary classifier ML model that takes a corpus of biomedical research paper and classify whether to curate or to discard. I have downloaded around 10000 articles (pdf) from PubMed, but how do I generate ground truth (labels/target variable) for all those 10000 articles. Can I use BioBERT to train these articles without labels? Could someone please clarify. Thanks

Comment: There is a method called `Zero-shot Learning` which may be useful for your application.

Comment: The primary way to get ground truth is to label documents, that is to go through them and mark what you want to do with them. How would you explain to a human whether to keep or discard a paper? An ML model can't read your mind.